# GoLang Issues displaying JSON results on HTML template

Tags: json, go

### **Context**:

Here is Struct:

```
type ReverseWhoisResponse struct {
    DomainsCount int      `json:"domainsCount"`
    DomainsList  []string `json:"domainsList"`
}
```

After doing everything that needs to be done, this is served to via:

```
c.HTML(200, "example.html", gin.H{
    "total":   ReverseWhoisResponse.DomainsCount,
    "list":    ReverseWhoisResponse.DomainsList,
})
```

The first part, of displaying raw JSON works just by

```
<pre>
  <span class="inner-pre">
     {{ .list}}
  </span>
</pre>
```

### **Issue:**

However, now i'm trying to display a parsed field as well - so that i can view both raw JSON in one tab, and parsed results in another. This is how i'm attempting to do it:

```
<ul>
    {{range .DomainsList }}
        <li>
            <span>{{ .list }}</span>
        </li>
    {{end}}
</ul>
```

This is because it returns a list of URLs

E.G

```
example1.com
example2.com
example3.com
```

I'm trying to parse it so it looks decent on screen so i can actually utilize it.

At the moment, i'm not getting any errors - but i'm seeing the RAW Json in the tab, but not seeing anything in Parsed tab, any ideas what's going on or some documentation i can follow for this?

Comment: Can you share the JSON you're using as input? If `{{.list}}` displays raw JSON, that suggests that `ReverseWhoisResponse.DomainsList` contains raw JSON, which suggests it isn't being parsed as you expect. Assuming your second template code block is the parsed tab, and that's receiving the the same `"total"` and `"list"` parameters as the raw JSON block, are you sure it would be passed `.DomainsList` and not just `{.list}`? Also, in the range function, do you mean to use `{{.}}` instead of `{{.list}}`?
Disclaimer: I have no experience with gin, so I'm guessing on some of this stuff. :)

Comment: {{.list}} returns something like this: 

[example1.com example2.com example3.com]

And no as for {{.}}, i've done this before with gin this exact same way, i'm reviewing my code trying to figure out if i'm doing something wrong

Comment: @SpencerConnaughton using {{range .}} and {{.domainslist}} returns: "<.DomainsList>: can't evaluate field DomainsList in type interface {}"

Comment: @SpencerConnaughton nvm you were right, can you post this as an answer so that i may mark as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was outlined by @spencerconnaughton.

My issue was that i was misusing ranges.

instead of:

```
<ul>
    {{range .DomainsList }}
        <li>
            <span>{{ .list }}</span>
        </li>
    {{end}}
</ul>
```

It should have been:

```
<ul>
    {{range .list }}
        <li>
            <span>{{ . }}</span>
        </li>
    {{end}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the JSON you're using as input? If `{{.list}}` displays raw JSON, that suggests that `ReverseWhoisResponse.DomainsList` contains raw JSON, which suggests it isn't being parsed as you expect. Assuming your second template code block is the parsed tab, and that's receiving the the same "total" and "list" parameters as the raw JSON block, are you sure it would be passed `.DomainsList` and not just `{.list}`? Also, in the range function, do you mean to use `{{.}}` instead of `{{.list}}`? Disclaimer: I have no experience with gin, so I'm guessing on some of this stuff. :)